# How can I simplify my jQuery animation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, simplify

How can I simplify my jQuery animation? What is the best way?

Code:

```
$("#nav").animate({opacity:0.2},1000);
$("#sub_nav").animate({opacity:0.2},1000);
$("#user_links").animate({opacity:0.2},1000);
$("#logo").animate({opacity:0.2},1000);
$(".top_buttons").animate({opacity:0.2},1000);
$(".pageheaders").animate({opacity:0.2},1000);
$(".heading_sub_text").animate({opacity:0.2},1000);
$("#copyright").animate({opacity:0.2},1000);
$("#footer_links").animate({opacity:0.2},1000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either give each of the elements a class (or an additional class):

```
$('.someNewClass').animate({opacity:0.2},1000);
```

Or place all your elements in one selector, separated by commas.

```
$("#nav,#sub_nav,#user_links,#logo,.top_buttons,.pageheaders,.heading_sub_text,#copyright,#footer_links").animate({opacity:0.2},1000);
```

Or a combination of the two, adding a class just the ones that don't currently have a class.

```
// These get .someNewClass: #nav,#sub_nav,#user_links,#logo,#copyright,#footer_links
$(".someNewClass,.top_buttons,.pageheaders,.heading_sub_text").animate({opacity:0.2},1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears that your are animating a group of elements, could you possibly wrap all of them in a div and then just animate that div?

Depending upon your needs, you may also want to look at [jQuery Tools' Expose](http://flowplayer.org/tools/toolbox/expose.html) functionality. It basically dims the background and highlights (or exposes) a particular object. The also have an overlay tool if that's more like what you are attempting to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

What patrick dw suggests will clean up your jQuery code substantially. Of his suggestions, I consider the first one the best. However, I will make a point that it is far more important to emphasize selector/effect optimization (over cosmetic improvements).

However, consider the following code.

```
var c = $('<div class="container" />').appendTo($('body'))
for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  c.append($('<div />')
   .css('height', 30)
   .css('width', 30)
   .css('borderWidth', 2)
   .css('borderStyle', 'solid')
   .addClass('anim'))
}
```

This creates `div.container` and puts 1000 copies of `div.anim` inside it. Do this, then compare the performance of `$('.container').fadeOut()` versus `$('.anim').fadeOut()`. Animating a containing div is orders of magnitude faster than animating its many children. If possible, always animate out a wrapper if you want to animate all of its children in an identical fashion.